# MSR Sweetwater dripping

Tags: water-purification

I just bought an MSR Sweetwater pump for a trip next week.  I'm pumping a few quarts now to clean it out, and notice that there is constant dripping water out of the pressure relief valve at the top (maybe three or four drops per stroke -- not a lot by any means).  There is certainly not a strong stream of water.  I scrubbed out the filter a couple times first as instructed.

I've never used one of these.  Is this the normal behavior?  If not, can I still go ahead and use it for the trip?

Comment: that sounds like a question the manufacturer would answer quickly and authoritatively.

Answer (score 2):

Water coming out of the pressure relief valve means that your filter is clogged, it say so in the instruction manual. Have you followed the "prepare filter surface" instructions? Did you remember to rinse the cartridge and pump out the loose carbon?